# can be delete of a element in a static array be O(1)?

Tags: java, data-structures

When you create an array, you are reservating size(type)*lenght in memory, and when you want to access to a particular position you can acces by size(type)*position, so if you want delete the last element you could only set the max value of position to position-1 and free the rest of the memory for get a delete in O(1)

Is this how works the static array for the las element?

Comment: Not in Java....

Comment: What do you mean by static array? Do you mean an object of an array type like `int[]`?

Comment: there is no such thing as "deleting an element" of statically created array (i.e. using square brackets)

Comment: @shmosel, so always will be O(n), can be in C for example of this way? I refer to a int[]

Comment: Also in C there's no such concept as "delete" from a static array. An array of 15 ints contains 15 ints, forever and always. There's no concept of "empty" element. Arrays of pointers may contain elements that are the NULL pointer, so that's occasionally used to make static lists of structures with a maximum size and allowing NULL elements.

Comment: And is the way of access to a particular position correct, for example if you want access to a position k, you onlye will need size(type)*k, in cost O(1) ?

Comment: You can achieve this with a custom list inplementation which is based on `ArrayList`.  I have implemented such a list before which just set its internal size counter to 0 in its `clear() ` implementation. Beware of holding on to unused chunks of memory when using this technique,  the GC cannot free any memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. The length of an array in Java is fixed. You can still delete objects at the end of the array by keeping a separate counter for the number of items in the array. Then you can "delete" the last element by setting it to null and manually reducing the counter. But the actual length of the array will still be same, the entries above the counter will just be empty.